# Why android made View a base class but not an interface?

Tags: android, interface, abstract-class, android-view

Recently I was thinking about View hierarchy in android and I faced with question in my mind, why Android SDK have base class View, but not, for example, interface View and base class BaseView.

As I know similar situation we have, for example, for Collections in Java. We have interface List and abstract class AbstractList, which implements it. Thus, we can provide on the one side a common logic for all 'sub'-views and on the other side common interface for, for example, mocking it in testing or something like that.

But instead of that, we need to use in tests emulator to retrieve some context, that we will pass to constructor of our 'stub' view, or for example mock context somehow (using robolectric, or try to mock yourself).

Moreover, I think it would be better to have sub-interfaces for TextView, EditText, or something like that. So, for example, if you have to implement your own CustomView class, you would need to create an interface CustomView and it's implementor. Something like: `class MyCustomView extends BaseView implements CustomView` and if it is needed `interface CustomView extends View`. I think, besides it askes from your side to write more code, It could make development process more flexible. For example, as I said for tests or for providing recently popular MVP (in other words to provide more loose coupling for components).

I don't know, maybe I missed something, and this approach is bad in Android, so could you, please, explain me why it is bad, or maybe share your thoughts about how it could be, or maybe current approach is just more simple, or we need to restrict developer from creating custom implementations of View interface (for example there is have to be a context reference in view, or something like that), or it's not bad approach, but because of backward compatability we need to use old way?

I will glad to hear your advize or thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: "Why android made View an abstract class?" -- `View` is not an `abstract` class.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks It was my typo. Updated my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly what you mean, but, if i transform the View in an Interface, what would i do if i need a View ? Currently i can just use a View, witch is the more basic of all Views Type, if it's an Interface i would need to implement some other element don't ?

Comment: I think that for Android, having `View` as a class rather than an interface was the correct design.  Everything in the Android UI has to draw on a `Canvas`, which needs to be managed by a class; also, touch events need to be handled and the appropriate callbacks made.  Just take a look at the `View` source code.  There is an *enormous* amount of housekeeping that goes on inside a `View`.  Things you wouldn't typically think about, like managing `Drawable`s.  I can't see how any of that would have benefited from pushing it into an interface implementation.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro as I said in my question current View we can rename to BaseView and create interface View, so on the one side we will have interface, on the other side base class that will have all, that has View class now.

Comment: @krislarson As I said, you still will have class that do all housekeepeng, but also you will have couple of interfaces that declare some possibilities of what you can do.

Comment: There's some differences in a Class and a Interface. A class describe the attributes and behaviors of an object, an Interface describes the methods (Abstracts) that the class implements. If the View is an Interface we will need an Abstract class to be the base to the interface and all the other views will need to implement ALL the methods from the interface. The View being a Class, implements intrinsic all the methods we need, and we can just override what you need to change, if it's an interface, you always will need to write a lot of methods to implement.

Comment: Maybe for create a `CustomView` may  be better (what i don't agree) ,  but if you just need to create one TextView, normal, it's better to implement all the methods from the interface ? I don't think so

Comment: If you want to create TextView you still can write TextView myTextView = new TextView(context); And as I said, you will still have base class (it will be called BaseView for example), but also ('also', not 'instead') you will have bunch of interfaces